# How to retrieve the token

Tags: slack, slack-api

I’ve completed the OAuth 2.0 flow and received the access token for my bot.
Of course every workspace in which the bot is installed needs a different access token.
Am I supposed to store a token for every workspace?
Or maybe is there a way to retrieve it on the fly when a user interact with the bot?

Comment: I think `App-level tokens` can do this....

Comment: You may be right, but I can't understand how to get one...can you help me?